# ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Tags: python, selenium

I have yet another question regarding `ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

I'm taking my first steps into python (trying to start QA automation route (Been a manual QA for years now)). So I tried looking this up in the web but no answer I found worked for me.

**Description (Skip if you want):** I'm trying to run a simple code to ask for an MTG card, then go look for its price (at a later iteration of this script, you will be able to pick and choose from a list of pages to query)

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from xpaths import *

card = input('What card are you looking for?')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
searchBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath(searchBox)
sleep(1)
searchBox.send_keys(card)
```

No matter what I try (slee, wait, clicking the element) I always get the same response
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

(BTW, Im trying to search for a card in starcitygames.com)

Any help will be appreciated, keep in mind this is my first real coding attempt.

**Edit:** 
I'm finding the element `searchBox` by its `xpath` = `searchBox = '//*[@id=\"search_query\"]'`

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show whats in `searchBox`?

Comment: My bad! searchBox = '//*[@id=\"search_query\"]'

Comment: Have u tried explicit wait until element is clickable?

Comment: I'm trying it now, but to no success. I'm trying to find the way to write it tailored to my need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ElementNotInteractableException occurs when an element is found, but you can't be interacted with. This could happen due to various reasons like element being not visible or displayed, element is off screen or element is behind another element or hidden. Try some of the actions below.

This looks like it's a dynamically generated element, so interact directly with DOM using the second method. Commands below are in Java syntax, you can research and apply the same relevancy to python.

1. Wait until an element is visible / clickable

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
```

2. Use JS Executor to interact directly with the DOM

```
JavascriptExecutor javascript = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
javascript.executeScript("var element = document.querySelector('locator'); element.value = 'whatever';")
```